# Lazarus - loading picture form file

Tags: image, file, lazarus

I have an issue with loading a picture from z file. The picture has a *.png* extension.
Can anyone explain me why it doesn't work anymore ?

```
 if (FileExists('file.png')) then
   Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('file.png');
```

Errors:

> Project project1 raised exception class 'PNGImageException' with message: This is not PNG-data
>
> Project project1 raised exception class 'FPImageException' with message: Wrong image format

Comment: You should use the full path of the image (eg. C:\myfolder\file.png). Also try a different png to make shure that your png is not invalid.

Answer (score 1):

At the first create your image component:

```
MyPicture := TImage.Create(FormCanvas);
MyPicture.Name := 'picture';
MyPicture.Parent := FormCanvas;
```

V1 - use direct path

```
Edit_pic_path.Text := 'C:\Images\';
Prop_Picture_Name.Text := 'image.png';

try
     if (FileExists(Edit_pic_path.Text + Prop_Picture_Name.Text)) then
     begin
       MyPicture.Picture.LoadFromFile(Edit_pic_path.Text + Prop_Picture_Name.Text);
     end;
  finally
  end;
```

V2 - image must be in project folder

```
...
MyPicture.Picture.LoadFromFile(Prop_Picture_Name.Text);
...
```